# VSCode Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+e renders as unknown instead of navigating to explorer window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to navigate to the explorer window via `Ctrl+Shift+e` but this sequence of keystrokes is not recognizable by `VSCode 1.55.2`.

I checked this two ways. First, via trying to check what `Ctrl+Shift+w` and `Ctrl+Shift+e` were binded to via keyboard shortcuts (`Ctrlk, Ctrls`) and then recording the keystrokes to reveal what they were binded to.

[image]

You will observe that `ctrl+shift+w` is recognized. Then, in the gif, when I press `ctrl+shift+e` it renders as `ctrl+shift+unknown`.

Then, whenever in a saved open file in the editor, when I press `ctrl+shift+e` hoping that the explorer navigator opens up on the left, that does not happen. Instead the file becomes unsaved with an underscore e appearing in the file.

[image]

This is completely new and strange behavior of the editor. I did not encounter this before.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Edited to add update: VSCode folks indicate that this is a known issue. Ctrl+shift+e translates into insertion of an emoji, it seems. See their comment [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121266#issuecomment-854972776).

Comment: Are you using Linux by any chance? I had a similar problem when I installed VSC from Snap, and reinstalling it the regular way fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I am on Linux. Let me try reinstallation. !@#$ :-( :-( :-(

Answer (score 8):

Same thing happened to me, using linux (ubuntu).

I installed it from the snap store, and tried reinstalling from there and the problem was still there.

Uninstalled and installed it manually from de .deb package at their webpage and it was solved.

Maybe it's an issue they have solved in the latest version (1.15.8) but it's still unsolved in the snap version (1.15.2 in your case, i didn't pay attention on what was my version).

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. Installing vscode from `.tar.gz` - works perfectly fine, installing from `snap` leads to unexpected behaviour on `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`E`